# Visual Studio to Qt Creator, no link to function definitions

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I worked on a Visual Studio project and I want to edit it with Qt Creator (I have a Makefile responsible for the build).

It works well but, for instance, I can't quick access to function definitions. It seems that there are no link between the file.

All of my files are listed into the the project `files` file and `includes` one. Here is the content of the `includes` file:

```
build_gcc/debugu
build_gcc/releaseu
build_vc10/debugu
src/Communication
src/Config
src/HMI
src/Main
src/Protocol
src/Res
```

Is there anything else to do ?

Comment: It is more related to the `files`file I suppose, you have both .h and .cpp in your list ?

Comment: @ymoreau Yes, I have all my files listed in the `files` file